# Using vim-surround for markdown

Tags: vim, markdown, vim-plugin

Is it possible to use vim plugin [`vim-surround`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) to wrap markdown?

For example I have code I would like to wrap

```
# ruby code here
```

with

````
```Ruby
# ruby code here
```
````

Comment: What does the documentation say? What did you try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` file:

````
let b:surround_{char2nr('r')} = "```Ruby\r```"
````

Select your lines of code via `V` then surround via `Sr`.

Comment: Now you can even make it ask for the desired language on the prompt with `let b:surround_{char2nr('r')} = "```\1language: \1\r```"` so it can be pretty generic for any language not only Ruby

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it does.

But you could try something like this:

````
xnoremap <leader>c c```Ruby<CR><C-r>"```<Esc>
````

Answer (score 0):

For markdown of a paragraph into a code block you can use this:

````
" markdown code for a paragraph
" vim-surround is great but it doesn't do this...
nnoremap <Leader>mdc {O<DOWN>```<DOWN><ESC>}i```<ESC><DOWN>O<ESC>
````

See this post for lots of vim tips: [Managing Vim and Essential Plugins](https://www.companionway.net/post/control_vim_and_plugins/)

Comment: As this is an older post your answe might be possible when OP asked it. You should add a software version to clear that up.